# Issues translating "get an ultrasound."

Tags: word-choice, nuances, word-requests

Talking about pregnancy with my Japanese friends has been a challenge because I have struggled to translate some English concepts.

`Ultrasound` is one of those words.

超音波｛ちょうおんぱ｝ is the word I find as the translation for `ultrasound.` However, because of the existence of the 波 character, I find that this is referring more to the ultrasonic *waves*, and not the procedure.  Is my suspicion warranted here?

Would it make more sense to say:

> 明日、超音波を受けてから赤ちゃんの性別が分かる。

or

> 明日、超音波で赤ちゃんの性別が分かる。

I'm leaning towards the use of で after 超音波, but I can't put my reasoning to words.  It just feels better to me.

Finally, is my next translation nonsensical?

> On the 24th, we are getting an ultrasound of the baby.
>   
> 24日に超音波で赤ちゃんの写真をとる。

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think 超音波を受ける is casually used, but 超音波*検査*を受ける might be better. You can also use エコー検査.　So how about saying...

> 「｛明日、/明日の｝｛超音波検査/エコー検査｝で、赤ちゃんの性別がわかる。」
>   「明日、｛超音波/エコー｝で赤ちゃんの性別がわかる。」
>   「明日｛超音波検査/エコー検査｝を受けて、赤ちゃんの性別がわかる。」

---

> On the 24th, we are getting an ultrasound of the baby.
>   24日に超音波で赤ちゃんの写真をとる。

Your sentence looks good to me. You can also use 超音波写真/エコー写真.

> 「２４日に赤ちゃんの｛超音波写真/エコー写真｝を撮る。」

Comment: 超音波 has been completely accepted as an abbreviated form of 超音波検査, but something like 超音波写真 or MRI写真 is technically incorrect and should be avoided at least in academic/technical contexts. I'm not stopping laypeople from using it in casual conversations, though...

Answer (score 1):

専門的{せんもんてき}には最初{さいしょ}の２文{ぶん}は少{すこ}し変{へん}なところもありますが、実用的{じつようてき}には、OPが提示{ていじ}した以下{いか}の表現{ひょうげん}はいずれも普通{ふつう}に使{つか}われており、意味{いみ}が通{つう}じると思{おも}います。

*The first two examples presented by OP sound a bit strange in the field of expertise, but in practical terms, I think that the following sentences are commonly used and make sense.*

- 明日、超音波を受けてから赤ちゃんの性別が分かる。
- 明日、超音波で赤ちゃんの性別が分かる。
- 24日に超音波で赤ちゃんの写真をとる。

To understand technical terms, please visit the following sites in Japanese.

- [超音波検査](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B6%85%E9%9F%B3%E6%B3%A2%E6%A4%9C%E6%9F%BB)
- [超音波映像装置](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B6%85%E9%9F%B3%E6%B3%A2%E6%98%A0%E5%83%8F%E8%A3%85%E7%BD%AE)
- [超音波断層撮影](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%B6%85%E9%9F%B3%E6%B3%A2%E6%96%AD%E5%B1%A4%E6%92%AE%E5%BD%B1)

In English, please read the following articles.

- [Non-contact ultrasound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-contact_ultrasound)
- [Medical ultrasound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_ultrasound)
- [Ultrasound computer tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasound_computer_tomography)

超音波{ちょうおんぱ} *ultrasound* を使{つか}った非破壊｛ひはかい｝検査{けんさ} *non-destructive testing* あるいは[非破壊]{ひはかい}[映像化]{えいぞうか}[装置]{そうち}の医療分野{いりょうぶんや}への応用{おうよう}あるいは実用化{じつようか}は日本{にほん}が先導{せんどう}してきた技術{ぎじゅつ}です。
対象物{たいしょうぶつ}を壊{こわ}さずに中{なか}の状態{じょうたい}を可視化{かしか}できますので、OPが話題{わだい}にしている妊婦{にんぷ}のお腹{なか}の赤{あか}ちゃんを見{み}るのに大変{たいへん}適{てき}しています。

「超音波{ちょうおんぱ}」を使{つか}った技術{ぎじゅつ}のどこを指{さ}すかによって用語{ようご}が色々{いろいろ}あり、「超音波{ちょうおんぱ}検査{けんさ}」「超音波{ちょうおんぱ}映像{えいぞう}装置{そうち}」「超音波{ちょうおんぱ}断層{だんそう}撮影{さつえい}」あるいは「超音波{ちょうおんぱ}診断{しんだん}」「超音波{ちょうおんぱ}診断{しんだん}装置{そうち}」のような専門{せんもん}用語{ようご}があります。
妊婦{にんぷ}のお腹{なか}の赤{あか}ちゃんを映像化{えいぞうか}（＝[可視化]{かしか}）する用語{ようご}として当初{とうしょ}用{もち}いられたものは、「超音波診断{ちょうおんぱしんだん}」、そして、それを実現{じつげん}する装置{そうち}である「超音波診断装置{ちょうおんぱしんだんそうち}」です。「超音波診断{ちょうおんぱしんだん｝」は「超音波検査{ちょうおんぱけんさ}」の一部{いちぶ}ですが、「検査{けんさ}」には映像化{えいぞうか}する対象{たいしょう}として物体{ぶったい}も含{ふく}まれますので、人体{じんたい}を対象{たいしょう}とする医療{いりょう}関係者{かんけいしゃ}あるいはそのための装置{そうち}を製造{せいぞう}する関係者{かんけいしゃ}の間{あいだ}では、「診断{しんだん}」という用語{ようご}の方{ほう}が好{この}んで使{つか}われていたように思{おも}います。むろん「レントゲン検査{けんさ}」のように医療現場{いりょうげんば}で「検査{けんさ}」という表現{ひょうげん}も普通{ふつう}に使{つか}われておりますので、お腹{なか}の赤{あか}ちゃんを見{み}るのに「超音波検査{ちょうおんぱけんさ}」と言{い}っても全{まった}く問題{もんだい}はありません。

Comment: 専門家でも論文とかでない限り「検査」はいちいち言わずに「超音波」と言うのが当たり前ですから「専門的には少し変」とは思いません。（わざわざ長く堅苦しく言いたい時に「超音波写真」というのは流石に不正確なので「超音波画像」などとすべきだとは思います）